# PHP script doesn't enter ELSE clause on IF statement (login test)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stumped on this one. Very simple login screen. When there is a password match the script works perfectly and jumps to main.php. When the uname or pswd is wrong, the script wont drop into the ELSE clause and wont go to badlogin.php. The script just hangs with the blank white screen.

any help would be great.

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");
$u_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$p_word = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pword']);
# *** querying all records ***
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notes_users WHERE valid_password = '$p_word' && valid_username = '$u_name'");
while($rst = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

if (($rst[valid_username] == $u_name) AND ($rst[valid_password] == $p_word)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = "1";
    header('Location: main.php') ;
} else {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = '';
    header('Location: badlogin.php') ;
}

}

?>
```

Comment: Have you yet proven that it *should* enter the `else` block?

Comment: Always use `exit;` after calling `header('Location: ...')` unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: Or `die(header(..));` which semantically makes more sense (to me, at least).

Comment: hmm... lemme do some proof work with: echo (($rst[valid_username] == $u_name) AND ($rst[valid_password] == $p_word));     ...and see how many TRUE matches I get

Comment: If user/pass is wrong, no results will return from your query, so you'll never enter the `while` loop because `mysql_fetch_array()` will return `false`.

Comment: Have you stepped through in a debugger?  If you can't do that, have you commented out the code in the `else` block, and replaced it with a line of test code: `echo "else block reached"`, to see if the problem lies elsewhere/

Comment: To expand on what @Wiseguy is saying: if the user/pass is wrong else is never reached because it's inside the while block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no results returned from the query then "while($rst = mysql_fetch_array($query))" will never prove true, and the while loop is skipped over entirely.

edit: You could change it to a "do while" or just fix your while conditional.

Answer (score 1):

You should have quotes around `valid_username` and `valid_password`. Right now, you are using them as constants. And you don't need the loop and `if` to check if the pair matches, you're already checking that on your query. <strike>I think your problem may be that you are comparing the values from the db with escaped values when you do that second comparison.</strike> Wiseguy and VDH are right, you never enter the `while` when the query returns `false`. Anyway, this simpler version should address all these issues:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("dbconnect.php");
$u_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$p_word = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pword']);
# *** querying all records ***
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notes_users WHERE valid_password = '$p_word' AND valid_username = '$u_name'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    $_SESSION['login'] = "1";
    header('Location: main.php') ;
} else {
    $_SESSION['login'] = '';
    header('Location: badlogin.php') ;
}
?>
```

Comment: i see what ur saying. gotcha it's working now. thanks very much! This is just a school project thus the plain-text passwords. noted....

Comment: Good to know, I was going to comment about that too!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some changes, you should not loop through the result if your only expecting a match:

```
<?php
//Session start at the top
session_start();
include("dbconnect.php");

$u_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$p_word = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pword']);

# *** querying all records ***
//Some changes, use a LIMIT clause unless your expecting multiple users
//And as your only checking for row existence there no need to return *
//And never have plain txt passwords in db, use at least sha1 and not md5
$query = mysql_query('SELECT 1 
                      FROM notes_users 
                      WHERE valid_password ="'.sha1($p_word).'" && valid_username = '.$u_name.'" LIMIT 1');

//assoc
$rst = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

//User found
if(mysql_num_rows($rst)==1){
    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
    header('Location: ./main.php');
    die;
}else{
//User not found    
    $_SESSION['login'] = false;
    header('Location: ./badlogin.php');
    die;    
}
?>
```